# Pass BusinessObjects user ID to CrystalReport

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, business-objects

Is it possible to pass a Business Objects user ID to a Crystal report at runtime? I know that the BO universe has a hidden parameter for this value, I'm hoping that CrystalReports/BO has a similar hidden parameter that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `CurrentCEUserID` property.  In the Document Properties section of the formula editor.